# Pivoting without pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pivot

I have been struggling to do this without `pandas`.
Can anybody help?

```
ID,Name,timstamp,IN_OR_OUT,Date
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 10:51:01,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 11:31:00,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 11:32:07,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 11:38:07,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 11:43:03,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 13:00:08,OUT,15-10-2018 
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 13:46:07,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 14:28:04,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 14:29:04,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 15:08:06,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 15:12:03,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 15:54:00,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 15:58:00,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 16:01:00,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 16:15:06,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 17:33:02,OUT,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 17:34:02,IN,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 17:45:04,OUT,15-10-2018
```

*So I want the final output to be like this*

```
ID,Name,timstamp,IN,OUT,Date
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 10:51:01,15-10-2018 11:31:00,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 11:32:07,15-10-2018 11:38:07,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 11:43:03,15-10-2018 13:00:08,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 13:46:07,15-10-2018 14:28:04,15-10-2018
103161,John Alex,15-10-2018 14:29:04,15-10-2018 15:08:06,15-10-2018
```

I know we can achieve this using `pandas` but is there anyway we can do this **without** `pandas`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this “without pandas”?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your input lines are stored in `lines` and they are ordered, i.e. consecutive entries belong together, then this is the solution:

```
for k, line in enumerate(lines):
    if not k % 2:
        out_line = line
    else:
        print(out_line.replace('IN', line.split(',')[2]))
```